# Get public IP from remote wireless access point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip, wireless-access-point

Is there a way to find out the public IP of a wireless access point in the "available networks" list without being connected to it?

Comment: If you are not connected to it then you can find almost nothing about an access point that it doesn't broadcast on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; in order to do this you need to be able to ping a "what is my IP?" service from the network used by the access point, which requires first being connected to it.